# How to use powershell command in cmd pipe?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

I want to use powershell's 'replace' in some long cmd.exe pipeline; how can I redirect from cmd to powershell input? The line below doesn't work, gives empty output:

```
c:\>(echo foo && echo bar) | powershell -Command "%{$_ -replace \"f\",\"x\"}"
```

Answer (score 5):

Based on [some further googling results](http://www.vistax64.com/powershell/81262-read-standard-input-stdin.html), adding `$input |` to powershell command seems to work, i.e.:

```
C:\>(echo foo && echo bar) | powershell -Command "$input | %{$_ -replace \"f\",\"x\"}"
xoo
bar
```

(note: when used in a .bat file, the `%` above needs to be replaced with `%%`, apparently)

Comment: 1) In CMD you should use & to string the execution of multiple statements, or may use carriage returns if the statements are wrapped in Parenthesis. && will cause CMD to do an unnecessary (in this example) evaluation on the first statement, and will only execute the following statement if the first was successful.

Comment: 2.a) In CMD we want to leverage for loops wherever possible because the scripting language is non Object oriented, However In PS it's preferable to act on the Object directly wherever possible since the language is OO.

Comment: 2.b) In your example the Loop provides no function and should be removed.

Comment: 3) The resulting code could simply be: `(echo foo & echo barf) | powershell -Command "$input -replace \"f\",\"x\""`